# Directory for PHP 5 FPM socket files is deleted after reboot on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php, php-fpm, socket

I've created a directory to store socket files for PHP 5 FPM: `sudo mkdir /var/run/php-fpm`. It is owned by `root:root` as well as core PHP FPM process.

When PHP FPM is starting, it creates socket files for each pool inside of this directory and nginx uses them to communicate.

However, when I reboot my machine (`sudo reboot`) this directory is gone after reboot and PHP FPM can't start, cause it can't create socket files inside of a missing directory.

What can be the problem? How do I debug it?

I'm using latest Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current version of Ubuntu is using so-called **up-start** configs to run services. More info about this can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto#Since_Ubuntu_6.10_.28Edgy_Eft.29).

All up-start scripts are located in the `/etc/init` directory. Do not confuse it with old init scripts in `/etc/init.d` directory.

As @Rhim stated in his answer, `/var/run` is a temporary mounted filesystem, that is *re-created* after each reboot, so changes are not persisted in it. So in order to have a custom directory for socket files you will have to create it every time. The best place to add such functionality is an upstart config for PHP FPM located in: `/etc/init/php5-fpm.conf`.

**Here's the modified version of this config:**

```
# php5-fpm - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager

description "The PHP FastCGI Process Manager"
author "Ondřej Surý <ondrej@debian.org>"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

# Precise upstart does not support reload signal, and thus rejects the
# job. We'd rather start the daemon, instead of forcing users to
# reboot https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/1272788
#
# reload signal USR2

pre-start script
    mkdir -p /var/run/php-fpm
    /usr/lib/php5/php5-fpm-checkconf
end script

respawn
exec /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf
```

`pre-start` stanza was already used to check PHP FPM configuration file so I've converted it to a script section and added my own command for creating the direcotry for socket files before calling the `checkconf`.

With this script it should work fine. In order to control state of the service use the `service` command like this: `service php5-fpm start`, `service php5-fpm restart` etc.

I hope it will help someone. Cheers!

Comment: isn't `/etc/init/php5-fpm.conf` file overwrited after php-fpm package is updated?

Comment: A valid concern. However, I'm not sure about this. I'm running this setup for at least half a year with automatic updates. No problems so far, no conflicts. etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in Ubuntu also!

```
cat /etc/redhat-release 
Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)

df -h /run
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3.9G  904K  3.9G   1% /run

ls -la /var | grep run 
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root      6 Dec 28  2013 run -> ../run

This directory is mounted as tmpfs.
```

Add to a startup script, create a directory or change the directory for pid files.
 But I am surprised that it is not created automatically after reboot.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is it OK to alter the `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm` script or is it better to create my own startup script then?

Comment: Show section start() in file `etc/init.d/php5-fpm`

Comment: I think you need to add `dir=$(dirname ${pidfile})
        [ -d $dir ] || mkdir $dir` 
in the beginning of the function start().

Variable `pidfile` must be defined `/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid`

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. Here's the requested piece of script: https://gist.github.com/slavafomin/cef2d5b0f6c6b5a011b2

Comment: PHP FPM is storing it's socket-files in the `/var/run` directory by default. I just wanted to group them together so I've created a sub-directory: `/var/run/php-fpm`. However it's deleted after each reboot.  How do I alter my starup-script to make sure it's working? I've tried to add `mkdir -p /var/run/php-fpm` in the begining of file, but it's not working for some reason.

Comment: Thanks! I've finally figured this out. Thanks for the pointer about `tempfs`.